# How to create custom Threshold in codeigniter for error logging

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want log the incoming HTTP request from clients and the response what my server gave them back.

Currently i have set the threshold to **DEBUG**. But this shows me all the class and models initialized.

But i just want some custom error to be logged an not all the CI logs.

So can i define a custom threshold to log my application's request response?

The config File:

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 2;
```

The Way i log my info:

```
log_message('debug', print_r($data, TRUE));
```

Comment: Show your code and how do you use it for now.

Comment: @Tpojka i have added the way i log my data

Comment: use try catch in codeigniter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670680/php-web-application-when-to-use-try-catch

Comment: @Bugfixer can i log this into log files?

Comment: You can do anything you want. Error mailing in live env. or log into error files.

Comment: But when i fetch the logs the logs threshold i set it to 2 so all debug logs are there in log file but i just want the logs that i created

Comment: @Rajan - This answer might help You http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209807/how-to-do-error-logging-in-codeigniter-php